# Use operator for failed tasks Airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow

I have a DAG with many tasks that are run in parallel.

[image]

- An EMR cluster is created
- Multiple EMR Steps are submitted,
- A `EMRStepSensor` is configured per `EmrAddStepsOperator` to wait for the result of the step.

I would like to send to send a SNS message if any of the steps have failed. I have seen a few approaches, like using another operator (`SnsPublishOperator`) with a property called `trigger_rule="all_done"`. I have tried something like this:

```
def get_sns_operator(self, emr_env):
    return SnsPublishOperator(
        target_arn=emr_env['snstopic'],
        message="Foo",
        subject="Report of execution",
        task_id="sns_notification",
        trigger_rule="all_done",
        dag=self.dag
    )


def define_workflow(self):
    common_args = CommonArgs(emr_env=Variable.get("consolidation", deserialize_json=True).get("emr"), other_args=self.other_args)
    cluster_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
        dag=self.dag,
        task_id='create_cluster',
        job_flow_overrides=common_args.jobflow_overrides_args(),
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        emr_conn_id='emr_default',
        region_name='eu-west-1'
    )
    tables = Variable.get("consolidation", deserialize_json=True).get(self.other_args['system']).get('tables')
    sns_operator = self.get_sns_operator(emr_env=Variable.get("consolidation", deserialize_json=True).get("emr"))
    for table in tables:
        step_args = copy.copy(self.other_args)
        step_args['table'] = table
        step_adder = EmrAddStepsOperator(
            dag=self.dag,
            task_id='step_{table}'.format(table=table),
            job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='create_cluster', key='return_value') }}",
            aws_conn_id='aws_default',
            steps=[common_args.step_args(**step_args)]
        )

        step_checker = EmrStepSensor(
            dag=self.dag,
            task_id='watch_step_{table}'.format(table=table),
            job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='create_cluster', key='return_value') }}",
            step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='step_" + table + "', key='return_value')[0] }}",
            aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        )
        cluster_creator.set_downstream(step_adder)
        step_adder.set_downstream(step_checker)
        step_checker.set_downstream(sns_operator)
    return self.dag
```

And effectively, the task is created successfully. But I wonder how to pass the info status or get it from the `watch_steps...` once they have all been completed and send message just in case there is an error.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you actually want the `one_failed` value for your `trigger_rule` -- this way you'll only receive a notification if any of the upstream tasks fail and you don't need to introspect any status: receive a notification, something needs fixing.

You can read more about the various trigger rules here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules

Comment: But I'd like the report once all tasks have been completed.

Comment: Then have a second task which does the same but with the default `trigger_rule` which waits for all upstreams to complete successfully.